# Groovy sql import error. Can not find property even though it's included

Tags: java, sql, groovy, gradle, classpath

When trying to run my program from the command line (works in intellij), i receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Sql for class: com...GetIpUtilization
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
at com.ibbs.unity.device.GetIpUtilization.run(GetIpUtilization.groovy:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:901)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:884)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.runScript(InvokerHelper.java:406)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$runScript.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
at com...GetIpUtilization.main(GetIpUtilization.groovy)
```

and this is where it says the error is

```
xbDbConn = Sql.newInstance(
   "jdbc:mysql://"+DATABASE_IP+":"+DATABASE_PORT+"/"+DATABASE_NAME+"?autoReconnect=true",
   DATABASE_USER,
   DATABASE_PASSWORD,
   "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
)
```

I am importing the groovy sql library like so:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
```

and I've tried

```
import groovy.sql.*
```

with no luck. I completely out of ideas at this point. And it's even more frustrating that it works in intellij but not by command line.

udpate

```
# groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.2.2 JVM: 1.7.0_51 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

# jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -jar CnrIpUtilHistory.jar

import com.cisco.cnr.sdk.client.*
import groovy.sql.*
import java.sql.SQLException
import com.cisco.cnr.sdk.*
import java.lang.*

import org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils

scriptDir = new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).parent
config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("${scriptDir}/ConfigIpUtilization.groovy").toURL())
DATABASE_IP = config.mysql.ip
DATABASE_PORT = config.mysql.port
DATABASE_NAME = config.mysql.name
DATABASE_USER = config.mysql.user
DATABASE_PASSWORD = config.mysql.password

SCOPE_DATABASE_IP = config.scope.ip
SCOPE_DATABASE_PORT = config.scope.port
SCOPE_DATABASE_NAME = config.scope.name
SCOPE_DATABASE_USER = config.scope.user
SCOPE_DATABASE_PASSWORD = config.scope.password


xbDbConn = Sql.newInstance(
   "jdbc:mysql://"+DATABASE_IP+":"+DATABASE_PORT+"/"+DATABASE_NAME+"?autoReconnect=true",
   DATABASE_USER,
   DATABASE_PASSWORD,
   "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
)
```

Comment: Can you paste a cut down script (including the includes) that fails, and the command line you use to run it, and the output of `groovy -version`

Comment: So you're running it somehow as a jar file?  Is groovy added to the classpath inside the manifest of this jar?

Comment: It's in included in the  gradle.build file.

Comment: The jar file doesn't know about the build.gradle dependencies.  Try:  `jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -cp /path/to/groovy/embeddable/groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:CnrIpUtilHistory.jar com...GetIpUtilization`

Comment: # jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -cp /home/*/.gvm/groovy/current/lib/groovy-ant-2.2.2.jar:CnrIpUtilHistory.jar com...GetIpUtilization -jar CnrIpUtilHistory.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class com...GetIpUtilization

Comment: You don't need the `-jar` bit. Try it like I had it, but put the full path to your main class where I had your obfuscated one from the question

Comment: /home/*/.gvm/groovy/current/lib/groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:CnrIpUtilHistory.jar com...GetIpUtilization
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Sql for class: com...GetIpUtilization
at

Comment: Can you post the actual command you're running? That looks like just a part of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was in the dependencies of the gradle.build file.

Changed the following lines in gradle.build from:

```
dependencies {
    groovy 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.2.2'
    ...
```

to:

```
dependencies {
    groovy 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.2'
    ...
```

This resolved the issue.